# JS Array.prototype.split() ignores the first character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanitization

I am currently working on a manual sanitization, that formates/fixes dates written
in this format **02101998** to *02/10/1998* (for example).
To achieve this, I want to chop any written input in smaller parts `(0210=> [[0],[2],[1],[0]])`
My method below ignores always the first written char.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setState(e.target.value);
    const partChars = e.target.value.split('');
    console.log(partChars);

  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onKeyPress={handleInput} defaultValue={state} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: _"Split() does ignore first character"_ - No, it doesn't (and why would it?) -> [mcve]

Comment: Use `onChange` instead of `onKeyPress` (your event is called before the typed key is added to the input's value, that's why it's always one char behind)

Comment: Christ has answered your question. Changing onKeyPress to onChange will fix the issue

Comment: See the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try onChange where you used onKeyPress. Actually, it is reading the value of the element when you press a second time.

```
...
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={handleInput} defaultValue={state} />
    </div>
  );
}
```